# UICollection View

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have a reusable collection view cell. I am trying to set an image at didselect at index path but when i select a cell it return more than cell returning same image.

Here is the code.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
  return 1
  }


func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

    cell.userImage.layer.cornerRadius = cell.userImage.frame.size.width/2
    cell.userImage.clipsToBounds = true

    return cell
  }




func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int{
  return 10
  }

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){

    let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    cell.userStatusImage.image = UIImage(named: "selectedcontact.png")

    collectionView.reloadData()

  }
```

Comment: I think you made mistake for your `numberOfSectionInCollectionView`, it should be 1, and `func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int)` is to set the number of cell you want to show in collectionView.

Comment: Even when i have one section the same problem is there.

Comment: So you mean after click there is still no image shown? can you maybe screenshot and post it here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep track of the selected cells.

```
    var selectedIndexes = [Int]()
    override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
            return 1
        }


   override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return 100
        }

   override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)
            if self.selectedIndexes.contains(indexPath.row){
                cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
            }
            else{
               cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            }

            return cell
        }

   // MARK: UICollectionViewDelegate
   override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

            if selectedIndexes.contains(indexPath.row){
                selectedIndexes.removeObject(indexPath.row)
            }
            else{
                selectedIndexes.append(indexPath.row)
            }
            collectionView.reloadData()
        }
```

Swift array don't have method to removeObject. Here is an extension for that

```
extension Array {
    mutating func removeObject<U: Equatable>(object: U) -> Bool {
        for (idx, objectToCompare) in self.enumerate() {
            if let to = objectToCompare as? U {
                if object == to {
                    self.removeAtIndex(idx)
                    return true
                }
            }
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the last line of code `collectionView.reloadData()` will reload all the cell to initial status since you don't have any place checking whether one specific cell is selected or not.